# How to choose AWS instance type

Tags: uiautomation, aws

We have desktop application written in Delphi and database SQLServer.
We use [testcomplete](https://smartbear.com/product/testcomplete/overview/#_ga=2.42987685.1690947794.1568245753-187173011.1511391989) to test each release.
now we are going to move those to AWS cloud.

How do I select proper instance type?

.....of course AWS site says m1 m3 for genaral M2 CR3 for memory intensive etc...but how much memory is memory intensive? testing application is graphic oriented but not as much as vidio processing.

What factors should I consider when it comes to testing eco-system?

Comment: _Amazon EC2 G3 instances are the latest generation of Amazon EC2 GPU graphics instances that deliver a powerful combination of CPU, host memory, and GPU capacity. G3 instances are ideal for graphics-intensive applications such as 3D visualizations, mid to high-end virtual workstations, virtual application software, 3D rendering, application streaming, video encoding, gaming, and other server-side graphics workloads._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it very much depends on your test purposes.

If you want to test the performance of your application, then you need to define some SLO/SLIs with the help of your product people. Only then you would know on what type of machines, what should be expected.

If it is a functional test, I go with a small instances to save money and if I see it is not enough, you can always easily use a better machine.